# Is there a word that means "to rotate into the correct position"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Say you have a rocket in the incorrect orientation, and it *moves* into the correct orientation, what is a word instead of *moves* that describes what the rocket did?

Comment: Hi user112513312, I have added the tag `single-word-requests` to this post as you are essentially looking for a word. Please include a usage sentence in accordance with the [tag-info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) that will attract more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *align*; depending on the exact situation, one or the other of these definitions might apply:

- to arrange things so that they form a line or are in proper position
- to change (something) so that it agrees with or matches something else

(source [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/align))

The rocket might be aligned with some target it is being launched towards, or simply with an imaginary line that it must be pointed along in order to reach its target.

Another possibility is simply *aim*.

Answer (score 2):

Re-orientation

( Orientation alignment , Orientation fit are two words )

Comment: *Reoriented* would better address the *single*-word request.